# Pasar dos variables por href con javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Construyo un tabla con php y mysql

```
$consulta = "SELECT id_inspirador, id_user, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, municipio FROM inspirador WHERE status_aprobacion is null order by fecha_capa desc";
    $registro = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

    $i=1;
    $tabla = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)) {

        $ver = '<a href=\"javascript:view_id_inspirador('.$row['id_inspirador'].');view_id_user('.$row['id_user'].')\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-theme05\" title=\"Datos del inspirador\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>&nbsp;';



        $tabla.='{"num":"'.$i.'","nombre":"'.$row['nombre'].'","ap_paterno":"'.$row['ap_paterno'].'","ap_materno":"'.$row['ap_materno'].'","municipio":"'.$row['municipio'].'","acciones":"'.$ver.'"},';
        $i++;

    }

    $tabla = substr($tabla,0, strlen($tabla) - 1);

    echo '{"data":['.$tabla.']}';
?>
```

Quiero pasar $row['id_inspirador'] y $row['id_user'] por url

```
      function view_id_inspirador(id_inspirador)
      {
        window.location.href='revision_documentacion.php?view_id_inspirador='+id_inspirador;
      }
      function view_id_user(id_user)
      {
        window.location.href='revision_documentacion.php?view_id_user='+id_user;
      }
```

Solo pasa id_user y si intento de esta forma me dice view_id_user=undefined

```
function view_id_inspirador(id_inspirador,id_user)
      {
        window.location.href='revision_documentacion.php?view_id_inspirador='+id_inspirador+'&view_id_user='+id_user;
      }
```

Comment: Te falta codigo para poder entender lo que estas queriendo hacer por ejemplo donde llamas a esas 2 funciones o a la ultima de javascript??

Comment: estoy perdiendo el valor, aun no intento hacer nada, solo quiero traer el valor para realizar alguna query con id_user, si yo quiero imprimir la variable con echo me dice undefined

Comment: Tienes que pasar las dos variables en un solo href . Y para ello debes modificar el PHP que arma la tabla .   En la variable $ver debes tener javascript:view_id_inspirador('.$row['id_inspirador'].','.$row['id_user'].') y asi utilizar la ultima opción de function_id_inspirador(id_inspirador, id_user ) . Espero se entienda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes agregar el valor de **id_user** también en el código PHP que usas para generar los links.

```
$consulta = "SELECT id_inspirador, id_user, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, municipio FROM inspirador WHERE status_aprobacion is null order by fecha_capa desc";
    $registro = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

    $i=1;
    $tabla = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)) {

        $ver = '<a href=\"javascript:view_id_inspirador(' . $row['id_inspirador'] . ', ' . $row['id_user'] . ');view_id_user('.$row['id_user'].')\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-theme05\" title=\"Datos del inspirador\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>&nbsp;';



        $tabla.='{"num":"'.$i.'","nombre":"'.$row['nombre'].'","ap_paterno":"'.$row['ap_paterno'].'","ap_materno":"'.$row['ap_materno'].'","municipio":"'.$row['municipio'].'","acciones":"'.$ver.'"},';
        $i++;

    }

    $tabla = substr($tabla,0, strlen($tabla) - 1);

    echo '{"data":['.$tabla.']}';
?>
```

Debes asegurarte que  `$row['id_inspirador']` y `$row['id_user']` no lleguen en `null` o vacíos por que te producirá un error de JavaScript